# How to terminate child process in other child process? (win32api)

Tags: c++, winapi

I created two child processes called p_1(notepad) and p_2(a clone of parent process) using CreateProcess.

What I want is terminate p_1 in p_2, not in parent process.

First, I created the processes with the following code:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    STARTUPINFO si = { 0, };
    WCHAR notepad[32] = L"C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe";
    WCHAR wndproc[32] = L"WindowProject.exe";

    if (true == CreateProcess(NULL, notepad, NULL, NULL, true, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &p_1))
    {   
        CreateProcess(NULL, wndproc, NULL, NULL, true, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &p_2);
    } 
}
    break;
```

When click the mouse left button, parent process creates two process

And here's the code to terminate p_1 process by right-clicking:

```
case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
{
    TerminateProcess(p_1.hProcess, 0);
}
    break;
```

However, the p_2 process can't terminate p_1, only the parent process can terminate p_1.

I thought it was because p_2 doesn't have a handle of p_1, so I added DuplicateHandle in after CreateProcess (I don't know this is the correct way to use DuplicateHandle):

```
if (true == CreateProcess(NULL, notepad, NULL, NULL, true, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &p_1))
    {   
        CreateProcess(NULL, wndproc, NULL, NULL, true, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &p_2);
        //give handle of p_1 to p_2
        DuplicateHandle(&p_1.hProcess, &p_1.hProcess, &p_2.hProcess, &p_2.hProcess, 0, NULL, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
    }
```

But the result was the same. So instead of DuplicateHandle I writed `p_2.hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, true, p_1.dwProcessId);` , but still the same result.

I wonder how p_2 can terminate p_1. Or which function is correct to use?

(I am a beginner in programming and this is my first time using stackoverflow. Please forgive me even if this is an inexperienced question.)

Comment: [Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects).

Comment: You called `DuplicateHandle` incorrectly. You failed to check the return value, so you never noticed. Also, you duplicated the handle of `p_1` into `p_2` but you never told the second process what the result was.

Comment: Thanks for comment. As a result of the second process, it was impossible to kill the first child process, but it was possible to create two child processes like the parent process did.

Comment: @IInspectable how would a Job object solve this task?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Shove `p_1` and `p_2` into the same Job Object, and either one can tear down the Job Object from within. This is a solution to the problem stated, though I should probably stop commenting on problem statements where the author is unable to communicate (or even understand) the problem they are trying to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable wouldn't that terminate both P1 and P2 at the same time? Nothing in the OP's question suggests that is the desired behavior. The question is how to let P2 terminate P1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DuplicateHandle()`, the parent can start P1 and P2, then duplicate its P1 handle into P2's context, then *pass the value of the duplicate handle to P2* via an IPC mechanism of your choosing, such as a pipe, window message, etc. P2 can then store the value into a `HANDLE` variable and terminate P1 using that handle.

Another option is to have the parent start P1 first, then use `SetHandleInformation()` to make its P1 handle inheritable, then start P2 with the `bInheritHandles` parameter set to true (and preferably with [the P1 handle specified explicitly via `STARTUPINFOEX`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873) instead of being inherited implicitly). Then the parent can pass the *value* of its P1's handle as a command-line parameter when starting P2, and then P2 can parse the parameter into a `HANDLE` variable that it can use to terminate P1.

Another option is the parent can start P1 first, and then pass P1's PID as a command-line parameter when starting P2, then P2 can parse the parameter into a `DWORD` variable and `OpenProcess()` the PID so it can then terminate P1 using the opened handle.

This 3rd approach does have a small risk, though, in that P1 *could* be terminated through other means after P2 has started and before P2 opens the PID, thus risking the PID being reused for a completely unrelated process. The 1st and 2nd approaches avoid that risk.

Comment: start P1 first and then pass P1's HANDLE to P2 as a command-line parameter

Comment: @RbMm That won't work, since the handle to P1 would only be valid in the context of the parent process, thus the need for the parent to `DuplicateHandle()` the handle into P2's context, which would require P2 to be started before duplicating.

Comment: no, this of course will be work, simply handle must be marked as inherited - so will be and in p2 and have the same value

Comment: I think this would be the right answer for me! I've never used pipe before, but I'll try this.

Comment: @Peroro321 - you not need any pipes and ipc here

Comment: @RbMm Fair enough. I added that to my answer.

Comment: we can use susch code - https://pastebin.com/XiriSqxG

Comment: `SetHandleInformation()` not need. need from begin create this handle as inheritable

Comment: @RbMm the parent process is creating P1 and P2 processes via `CreateProcess()`. The OP wants P2 to terminate P1. But `CreateProcess()` does not return an inheritable handle for the new process, so yes, `SetHandleInformation()` (or `DuplicateHandle()`) is needed to make the P1 process handle inheritable so the P2 process can inherit it

Comment: *But CreateProcess() does not return an inheritable handle for the new process,* - this is not true. look for 3-parameter. and/or my implementation - https://pastebin.com/XiriSqxG (line 44)

Comment: sorry. I did not understand that "pass the handle as a command-line parameter". What do I need to do in my code to do that?

Comment: @Peroro321 - https://pastebin.com/XiriSqxG use this code